# Two Way DataBinding in Java (Programmatically)

Tags: java, android, android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding

The following code is defining `user.firstName` to `EditText` by two-way binding approach.

```
<EditText android:text="@={user.firstName}" .../>
```

Is there anyway how to set `user.firstName` to `EditText` in Java Code programmatically by two way binding approach.

For example;

```
editText.setTextbyTwoWay(user.fisrtName);
```

P.S: I forgot to describe the `EditText` is created programmatically in **Java Code**. That's why I have to define **Text value** to this `EditText` in Java Code for `two-way binding`.

Comment: Observer design pattern may be!?

Comment: You can implement it with `ObservableField`

Comment: DataBinding is used to write less code in your java file, why do you want to implement two-way binding in java code?

Comment: if you linked your xml to 'user' data model then any changes in datamodel will change the view also!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this within the `Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback.onPropertyChanged()` and `TextWatcher.afterTextChanged()` callbacks. But this is a quite extensive implementation and does exactly what would be done within the data bindings.

So you should consider to still use data bindings for the view you define programmatically. Define as much as possible in layout and then inflate it with data bindings. Further customization can be done on the inflated view.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android>
    <data>
        <variable name="user" type="my.User" />
    </data>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:text="@={user.firstName}"
        [...] />
</layout>
```

Now you only need to add the binding root view instead of the `EditText`.

```
EditTextBinding binding = EditTextBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
EditText editText = binding.editText;
View viewToAdd = binding.getRoot();
```